# Create a new DevOps project (Python Function) fails with ServerFarmNotFound error

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions

I tried to create a brand new Azure Function from the Azure Portal using new > DevOps project.
The release pipeline fails with the following log:

```
2020-01-17T19:30:42.8797302Z ##[error]The template deployment 'python-functionapp-template-consumption-20200117-193042-18b5' is not valid according to the validation procedure. The tracking id is '979a2fc4-5d2d-4aa2-a48a-9a4aeba7029c'. See inner errors for details.
2020-01-17T19:30:42.8797777Z ##[error]Details:
2020-01-17T19:30:42.8798134Z ##[error]ValidationForResourceFailed: Validation failed for a resource. Check 'Error.Details[0]' for more information. [{"code":"ServerFarmNotFound","message":"The specified app service plan was not found."}]
2020-01-17T19:30:42.8798592Z ##[error]Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.
```

PS: Region is West Europe

Comment: I'm not sure what `new > DevOps project` means, but this clearly says that the App Service Plan you are attempting to use doesnt exist

Comment: True, it should be created by the ARM template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting the issue. I also am seeing the same at the moment while selecting . Trying to create it in a different region (South Central US) doesn't work either. However, it is interesting to see that the same operation works when selecting a dedicated hosting plan as shown in the screenshot below:

[image: Create new Azure DevOps Project]

You may use this as a workaround if you see fit. I'd recommend you to create a new ticket in the [Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/21/index.html) for Azure DevOps so you can get assistance from our Team.

Meanwhile, if you want to try deploying Azure Functions in Python with Azure DevOps in a more manual way, here are a couple resources:

- [Deploying Azure Functions in Python with Azure DevOps](https://clemenssiebler.com/deploy-azure-functions-python-azure-devops/)
- [Create & Deploy Azure Function using VS code and Azure DevOps (CI/CD)](https://dev.to/usmslm102/create-deploy-azure-function-using-vs-code-and-azure-devops-ci-cd-3kmb)

Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Done! https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/892009/create-a-new-devops-project-python-function-fails.html

Comment: @RudyCo Glad you were assisted! Meanwhile, please feel free to mark and close this one out if the above response helped so it can also benefit others in the community. Thanks!

Comment: I will close it as soon as I can confirm it works fine on my side. Flagging it as "answered" is not helpful if the fix is not deployed.

Comment: Finally fixed and available (tested in West Europe)